# DIV background disappearing when child image is positioned absolute

Tags: css, html, joomla

I'm trying to make a Joomla template and I have a strange problem with my HTML and CSS code. I have a footer with some Text an Joomla module and an img. When I try to bring the image to the right side of the footer by seting position to absolute and right to 0 the background of my footer disappears.

My HTML code:

```
<footer>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p><jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" /></p>
    <img src="<?php echo $templateDir;?>/images/footerBgR.png"/>
</footer>
```

My CSS code:

```
footer {
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 10% 0px 10%;
    background: #292929;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

footer p {
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 3px 0px 0px 10px;
}

footer img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

When I remove "position: absolute;" the background is shown but the image is not where I want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to give a height to the footer

```
footer {
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 10% 0px 10%;
    background: #292929;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height:100px;
}
```

change the footer height as per your image height.

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/FKBBh/)

you can do this by this way also

give `height: 100% and overflow: hidden` to the footer and remove thr absolute position from image and give `float: right`

```
footer {
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 10% 0px 10%;
    background: #292929;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

footer img {
    float:right;
}
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/FKBBh/1/)

Comment: Thanks that did it. I didn't think that it would be that easy xD

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` to your image.

```
footer img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```